# Prove that two transitive closures are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

Suppose I am given two transitive closures $R^{+}_1$ and $R^{+}_2$ on the same binary relation $R$ over a set $A$, what steps would I take to show that $R^{+}_1 = R^{+}_2$ ?

$R^{+}_1$ is defined using a basis (if $(x, y) \in R$, then $(x, y) \in R^{+}_1$) and induction (if $(x, y) \in R^{+}_1$ and $(y, z) \in R^{+}_1$, then $(x, z) \in R^{+}_1$). $R^{+}_2$ is defined using a recursive construction. I followed the [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Recursive_Construction_of_Transitive_Closure) for a proof for the recursive definition.

Would it suffice to prove each individually, and since they are both closures over the same binary relation $R$, conclude that they are equal?

Comment: Surely $R_1^*\cap R_2^+$ is also a transitive relation containing $R$.

Comment: So since the transitive closure of $R$ is the intersection of all transitive relations containing $R$, showing that $R^{+}_1  \cap R^{+}_2$ is the same as showing they are equal?

Answer (score 1):

Let T be the transitive closure of R.
T is the smallest transitive relation containg R.
If T' is a transitive closure of R,
then since closures are the smallest
T subset T' and T' subset T;  T = T'.

To show that a relation R for a set S always has a transitive closure, show:
R subset S×S and S×S is transitive;
the intersection of a collection transitive relations is transitive.

With that it is easy to see that
$\cap${ T : T transitive relation for S, R subset T }
is the transitive closure of R.

Afterwards one can show the recursive construction is the closure by showing:
the construction creates a transitive relation containing R;
every transitive relation containing R contains all the ordered pairs of the construction.

Comment: Regarding the steps to be taken, I need to show that $R^{+}_1$ and $R^{+}_2$ is transitive, that $R$ is in $R^{+}_1$ and $R^{+}_2$ and every transitive relation that has $R$ is a superset of $R^{+}_1$ and $R^{+}_2$?

Comment: @dreamin.   The transitive closure of R is $\cup${ R$^n$ : n nonnegative integer }.